# Várias thread podem interferir no timerControl

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que contém mais de 10 threads em execução ... surgiu a necessidade de ter dois timers, um para bloquear e outro para liberar um processo, por isso estou usando o timerControl do WinForms ...

que inicialmente são: `timer.Enable = false / timer.Interval = 100;` 
no momento certo, eu colocá-los desta forma: `timer.Interval = 60000 (1min) /timer.Enable = true`;

mas eles nunca ficam ativos .... eu já tentei usar `timer1.Start ()` junto, mas não funcionou...

Alguém sabe se isso é por causa das threads ou não...já pesquisei na net mais não encontrei nada parecido

Comment: eu não conheço muito de C#, mas se utilizar a API do windows, pode utilizar o método `GetTickCount` que é a contagem de milisegundos desde que o sistema iniciou. Tem algumas pegadinhas como reinicia após 40,5 dias e não incrementa em computadores hibernados mas é thread safe e pode lhe ajudar

Comment: bom eu consegui usá-los da seguinte forma deixando ele ativo desde o começo e quando a condição de teste for verdadeira eu mudo seu intervalo(dentro do evento tick foi a única forma de mudar)e assim q a condição deixa de ser verdadeira mudo novamente o tempo.Mas o queria mesmo é descobrir o motivo...mas vlw

Comment: Quem bom, é sempre bom descobrir soluções. Se quiser então, pode responder a sua própria pergunta e marcar como correta, daí outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida podem se beneficiar também da sua solução.

Answer (score 1):

bom eu consegui usá-los da seguinte forma deixando ele ativo desde o começo e quando a condição de teste for verdadeira eu mudo seu intervalo(dentro do evento tick foi a única forma de mudar)e assim q a condição deixa de ser verdadeira mudo novamente o tempo.Mas o queria mesmo é descobrir o motivo...mas vlw